# NodeJS express-session with redis in typescript not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I use express-session with a redis store in my NodeJS backend. When I just used javascript, everything worked well:

```
const express               = require('express');
const session               = require('express-session');
const redis                 = require('redis');
const RedisStore            = require('connect-redis')(session);
const app = express();

let redisClient = redis.createClient(6380, process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME, {auth_pass: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY, tls: {servername: process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME}});
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
}));
```

After upgrading to typescript, I wasn't able to reuse the same code. That's how my code looks now:

```
import express          = require('express');
import session          = require('express-session');
import redis            = require('redis');
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
const app = express();

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: "rediss://" + process.env.REDISCACHEHOSTNAME + ":6380",
    password: process.env.REDISCACHEKEY,
});
redisClient.connect().then(() => {
    const redisStore = new RedisStore({ client: redisClient });
    app.use(session({ store: redisStore }));

    ... some app routes
});
```

It seems to connect, but when I try to update my session like:

```
req.session.user = { ... }
```

I get the following error:

> xxx\backend\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\RESP2\encoder.js:17
> throw new TypeError('Invalid argument type');
> ^ TypeError: Invalid argument type
> at encodeCommand (xxx\backend\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\RESP2\encoder.js:17:19)
>
> at RedisCommandsQueue.getCommandToSend (xxx\backend\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\commands-queue.js:187:45)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Update your typescript version. Use major version greater than 4.1.0. 
For more details check the issue on GitHub : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/62264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue if I don't pass the [`legacyMode : true`](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#api) option.

Strange thing is that the documentation states this option is required for Redis v4 and up, but I was able to reproduce the same issue on v3.2.5 when the option isn't set.

Comment: When I use legacyMode: true it is working. But why isn't it working without?

Comment: I think [this comment](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/361#issuecomment-1182015683) explains why.